# Content is hidden mobile device

Tags: html, css

I am building a website using HTML and CSS. The problem:when accessing the website on a mobile device it will not show all the content, basically parts of the text, buttons, fields are hidden.

Please have a look at the pictures I have attached to have a better understanding. Thanks

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnKBk.jpg)

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JZ3A.jpg)

```css
/* ==== Google font ==== */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,400italic,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700');
/* === fontawesome === */
@import url('font-awesome.css');
/* ==== overwrite bootstrap standard ==== */
@import url('overwrite.css');
@import url('animate.css');

body {
 font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:300;
 line-height:1.6em;
 color:#000;
 background-color:#fff;
}

hi,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 color:#000;
 line-height:1.1em;
}

p {
 color:#000;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration:none; 
}
.navbar-default {
 margin-top:-10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius:0; 
 border:0; 
}

.container-fluid > .navbar-header {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top:20px;
 border-radius:0;
}
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand h1 {
 float: left;
 line-height:20px;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-top:-15px;
 color:#6D9C91;  
}
.navbar-brand h1:hover {
  background-color:#fff;
}

.navbar-brand img{
 float: center;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: -35px;
}

.menu {
 font-size:14px;
 float:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:500;
 
}

.menu ul.nav-tabs li {
 color:#000; 
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a { 
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
 border-radius:0;
 color:#000;
 border-top:0;
 border-right:0;
 border-left:0; 
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eee #eee #6D9C91;
  color: #6D9C91;
  border-radius:0;
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
  
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #6D9C91;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  cursor:pointer;  
}

/*===========================
  slider
============================ */
.slider {
 position: relative; 
 margin-top:-20px;
}

.slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

#carousel-slider {
  position: relative;
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -40px;
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-indicators li {
  border: 1px solid #ffbd20;
}

#carousel-slider a i {
 border-radius:50%;
 font-size: 30px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 50px;
 color:#6d9c91;
 background:#6d9c91;
 color:#fff;
}

#carousel-slider a i:hover {
 background:#6d9c91;
 color:#fff;
 border: 1px solid #6d9c91;
}

#carousel-slider 
.carousel-control {
 width:inherit;
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-control.left i {
 left:50px;
 top: calc(50% - 50px);
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-control.right i {
 right: 50px;
 top: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.carousel-caption {
 position: absolute;
 right: 15%;
 top: calc(50% - 150px);
 font-size:40px;
 left: 15%;
 z-index: 10;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

.carousel-caption  h2 {
 font-size:40px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.carousel-caption  h2 span {
 font-size:40px;
 color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption  p {
 font-size:25px;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 color:#fff;
 padding:10px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-caption  {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h2, .carousel-caption  h2 span, .carousel-caption  p {
     font-size:18px;
    }
}

.carousel-inner .form-inline .form-group button[type="livedemo"]{
 padding:20px 60px;
 font-size:20px;
 background:#6d9c91;
 color:#fff;
 border-radius:0;
 border-color:#fff;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.carousel-inner .form-inline .form-group button[type="livedemo"]:hover {
 color:#fff;
 opacity: 0.8;
 -webkit-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  -moz-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  -o-transition:  color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  transition:  color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
}

.carousel-inner .form-inline .form-group button[type="getnow"]{
 padding:20px 60px;
 font-size:20px;
 background:#fff;
 color:#272727;
 border-radius:0;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.carousel-inner .form-inline .form-group button[type="getnow"]:hover {
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#fff;
 background:#6d9c91;
 -webkit-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  -moz-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  -o-transition:  color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  transition:  color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .sign-up-form .form-control {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .sign-up-form .btn {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sign-up-form .form-control {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

.content {
 background-color:#f9f9f9;
 padding:50px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top: -50px;
 
 
}
.content  span {
 color:  #154360;

}
.content p {
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 color: #0b5345 ;
}
.breadcrumb  {
 padding:30px;
 
}
.breadcrumb h4 {
 color:#6D9C91;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}
.breadcrumbs  {
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 padding:30px; 
}
.breadcrumbs h4 {
 color:#6D9C91;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}

.contents {
 margin-top:10px;
 
}
.contents p {
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.bg {
 margin-top:10px;

}
.recent button.btn-primarys h3 {
 padding:10px;
 font-size:30px; 
 text-decoration:0;
 color:#fff; 
}

.align-center {
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#fff;
 color:#000;
 padding:60px;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:30px; 
}
.align-center  p {
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.align-center:hover {
 border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
 border-color:#6D9C91;
 margin-top:-5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 4px rgba(204,204,204,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 4px rgba(204,204,204,1);
box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 4px rgba(204,204,204,1);
}
.boxs {
 margin-top:30px;

}
.icon {
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 color:#6D9C91;
}

.ficon i {
 color:#6D9C91;
}
/* --- Feature --- */
.feature {
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.feature p {
 margin-top:-30px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 padding:30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: proxima-nova;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.feature h1{
 font-family: proxima-nova;
 font-size: 25px;
}

/* --- Portfolio --- */

.col-md-6{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.col-md-4{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}


}
.portfolios { 
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
 padding:90px 0 90px 0;
}


.portfolio {
 margin-top:5px;
}

.list-group {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top:50px;
 
}
.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.list-group-item.active {
 
 background-color:#eee;
 border-color:#eee;
 color:#6D9C91;
}
.list-group-item.active:hover {
 background-color:#6D9C91;
 border-color:#6D9C91;
}
.list-group-item.active p.list-group-item-text {
 color:#000;
}
.image {
 margin-top:80px;
}
/* --- Blog --- */

.page-header {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-top:50px;
}

.blog h5 {
 color:#000;
 margin-left:20px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.blog img {
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px; 
}

.blog h3,p {
 color:#000;
 padding:15px;
}
.blog .ficon {
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.form-search .form-control {
 margin-top:20px; 
}

.media h4 {
 color:#000;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.media-body .ficon {
 float:right;
 margin-right:30px;
}
.media-body h4 {
 color:#000;

}
.media-list {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left:90px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.panel {
 margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border:#eee 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  text-align:center; 
}

.panel-default {
  border-color: #eee;
  border-bottom-color:#eee;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6D9C91;
  border-color: #eee;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-top-color: #eee;
   border-bottom-color:#eee;
}
.panel-default > .panel-footer + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
  border-bottom-color: #eee;
}

.list-group h5 {
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:-5px;
 background:#50c0e9;
 
 padding:15px 20px;
}
.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color:#000;
}
.list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.list-group-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.list-group-item > .badge {
  float: right;
  border-radius:0;
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
}
.popular-tags h5 {
 color:#6D9C91;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 text-align:center;
}
.popular-tags ul.tags {
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left:0;
 
}
.popular-tags ul.tags li {
 margin:0 5px 15px 0;
 display:inline-block;
}
.popular-tags ul.tags li a {
 background:#eee;
 color:#333;
 padding:5px 10px;
}
.popular-tags ul.tags li a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6D9C91;
}

/* --- Contact area --- */
form {
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}
label {
 color:#6D9C91;
 font-size:14px;
}
.form-group button {
 background-color:#6D9C91;
 color:#fff;
}
.form-control { 
 border-radius:0;
}
address {
 text-align:center;
 font-size:15px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding-bottom:30px;
 color:#333;
}
address br {
 margin-top:10px;
}

/* --- Map --- */
.map{
 position:relative;
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}

/* google map */
#google-map{
    position:relative;
    height: 350px;
}

.widget {
 margin-top:10px;
 padding:50px;
 text-align:center;
}
.widget p,ul {
 margin-top:30px;
}

.link-list ul,li,a {
 color:#000; 
 list-style:none;
 
}
.copyright {
 text-align:center;
}
.copyright a {
 color:#fff;
}

.sub-footer {
  background-color: #6D9C91;
}
ul.social-network {
 list-style:none;
 margin-top:30px;
 text-align:center; 
}

ul.social-network li {
 display:inline;
 margin: 0 5px;
 color:#fff;
}
ul.social-network li a { 
 color:#fff;
}

.credits {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.validation {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:13px;
}

#sendmessage {
    color: green;
    border:1px solid green;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#errormessage {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#sendmessage.show, #errormessage.show, .show {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Kafeyz</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/responsive-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <div class="navbar-brand">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"/></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html">Coffee Shops</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="users.html">Coffee Lovers</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  
  <div class="slider no-padding-bottom">
    <div id="about-slider">
      <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/slide1.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption no-padding-bottom">
              <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <h2><span>Take your business to the next level</span></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
      <p>A unified platform with everything your coffee shop needs</p>
      <p>&bull; mobile app &bull; supplies &bull; marketing &bull; training &bull; staffing solutions</p> 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                <form class="form-inline margin-top sign-up-form">
                <input id="email_intro" type="email" placeholder="enter email address" class="form-control">
                <input id="submit_intro" type="submit" value="Get started for FREE" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        
      </div>
      <!--/#carousel-slider-->
    </div>
    <!--/#about-slider-->
  </div>
  <!--/#slider-->



  <div class="content">
  </div>
 <div class="feature">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/1.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <h1>Mobile Ordering App</h1>
          <p>Improve your customers experience with an intuitive mobile ordering app 
     that will allow them to order their drink and food in advance. 
     Reduce queues, serve more clients and increase your revenue.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/4.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <h1>Supplies & Equipment</h1>
          <p>All the coffee shop supplies you need to offer delicious beverages any time of the day to your customers. 
    Order products like milk, pastries, and paper goods at competitive prices, with just one invoice.
          </p>
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/5.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <h1>Digital Loyalty Program</h1>
          <p>You cannot use paper cards to communicate with customers. 
    With your digital loyalty program, you now have a direct communication channel. 
    Send a push notification to your customers and encourage them to visit you again! 
          </p>
        </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/6.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <h1>Customized Mobile Marketing</h1>
          <p> You now have access to a wealth of data, allowing you to further tailor your marketing campaigns, 
    offers, and the entire customer experience to each individual.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/3.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <h1>Staffing Solutions</h1>
          <p> Book trained & experienced staff for temp or permanent jobs. Access professional training courses 
    that will help your staff to maintain the quality of your service to a very high standard.
          </p>
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="img/2.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    <h1>Workspace Bookings</h1>
          <p>The rise of the freelance and gig economy is bringing more and more people to coffee shops, where they set up a virtual office to work. 
   Add a new revenue stream to your business by offering workspace bookings at your café.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>


  <!--start footer-->
  <footer>

    <div class="sub-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="social-network">
              <li><a href="#" data-placement="top" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-1x"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-placement="top" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/kafeyz/" data-placement="top" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-1x"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-placement="top" title="Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-1x"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-placement="top" title="Google plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-1x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="copyright">
              <p>&copy;2018 Kafeyz - All rights reserved.</p>
              <div class="credits">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!--end footer-->

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/responsive-slider.js"></script>
  <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    wow = new WOW({}).init();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll more than likely have a media query in your CSS file hiding certain elements after a specific width threshold to stop the smaller screens from having too much content crammed in. - A copy of your CSS would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide your full code, including the CSS.

Comment: or you can add extra classes for small devices like col-sm-12 or col-xs-12 etc

Comment: I have added a full copy of the CSS and HTML code

Comment: you are using bootstrap to make page responsive then try to use bootstrap classes in all elements and divide the page as per your need and as per device size

Comment: @lewisnewson I have added a full copy of the CSS and HTML code

Comment: @rojadesign I have added a full copy of the CSS and HTML code

Comment: @AdeshKumar

Thanks Adesh. I am quite new to this, so don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: it's a bulk of code that we have to write. please try again and ask if specific portion is worrying you. Then only i will be happy to help

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Comment: check if you get anything from here

Comment: @AdeshKumar

The section I am having trouble is "Slider" - first section after "Header". Only part of the content in that section is displayed on mobile, more specific : Heading, Sign up field, second paragraph are hidden.

Thanks